# REST domino data services mailbox appointment compute with form error

Tags: rest, lotus-domino

I am developing a client application to integrate with Domino 8.5.3 (I have added the OSGI pack from openntf). Specifically when trying to add a new appointment via domino data services, I can add the document using the call to

```
http://xx.xx.xx.xx/mail/administ.nsf/api/data/documents?form=Appointment
```

but if I try and use the compute with form option ie

```
http:/xx.xx.xx.xx/mail/administ.nsf/api/data/documents?computewithform=true&form=Appointment
```

I get a 400 error (bad request) the error as show below. I have also tried to ad a reservation in the Resource and reservation database and the computewithform works. Any ideas why the appointments form doesn’t allow the computewithform option ?

Error Trace :

"code":400,
    "text":"Bad Request",
    "message":"@Function is not valid in this context",
    "type":"text",
    "data":"NotesException: @Function is not valid in this context

> lotus.domino.local.Document.NcomputeWithForm(Native Method) 
>   lotus.domino.local.Document.computeWithForm(Unknown Source) 
>   com.ibm.domino.das.resources.DocumentCollectionResource.postDocument(DocumentCollectionResource.java:162)
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611) 
>   org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.InvokeMethodHandler.handleRequest(InvokeMethodHandler.java:63)
>   org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandler.handleRequest(AbstractHandler.java:33)
>   org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
>   org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
>   org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:63)
>   org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.CreateInvocationParametersHandler.handleRequest(CreateInvocationParametersHandler.java:54)
>   org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
>   org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
>   org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:63)
>   org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleResourceMethod(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:151)
>   org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleRequest(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:65)
>   org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
>   org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
>   org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:63)
>   org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindRootResourceHandler.handleRequest(FindRootResourceHandler.java:95)
>   org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
>   org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
>   org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:63)
>   org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.HeadMethodHandler.handleRequest(HeadMethodHandler.java:53)
>   org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
>   org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
>   org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:63)
>   org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.OptionsMethodHandler.handleRequest(OptionsMethodHandler.java:46)
>   org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
>   org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
>   org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:63)
>   org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.SearchResultHandler.handleRequest(SearchResultHandler.java:33)
>   org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
>   org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
>   org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:63)
>   org.apache.wink.server.internal.log.ResourceInvocation.handleRequest(ResourceInvocation.java:92)
>   org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
>   org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
>   org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:63)
>   org.apache.wink.server.internal.log.Requests.handleRequest(Requests.java:76)
>   org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
>   org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
>   org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:63)
>   org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.run(AbstractHandlersChain.java:48)
>   org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor.handleRequestWithoutFaultBarrier(RequestProcessor.java:207)
>   org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor.handleRequest(RequestProcessor.java:154)
>   org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.RestServlet.service(RestServlet.java:119)
>   com.ibm.domino.services.AbstractRestServlet.doService(AbstractRestServlet.java:70)
>   com.ibm.domino.das.servlet.DasServlet.doService(DasServlet.java:182) 
>   com.ibm.domino.services.AbstractRestServlet.service(AbstractRestServlet.java:55)
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:806) 
>   org.eclipse.equinox.http.registry.internal.ServletManager$ServletWrapper.service(ServletManager.java:180)
>   org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.handleRequest(ServletRegistration.java:90)
>   org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:111)
>   org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:67)
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:806) 
>   com.ibm.domino.xsp.adapter.osgi.OSGIModule.invokeServlet(OSGIModule.java:165)
>   com.ibm.domino.xsp.adapter.osgi.OSGIModule.access$0(OSGIModule.java:151)
>   com.ibm.domino.xsp.adapter.osgi.OSGIModule$1.invokeServlet(OSGIModule.java:132)
>   com.ibm.domino.xsp.adapter.osgi.AbstractOSGIModule.invokeServletWithNotesContext(AbstractOSGIModule.java:179)
>   com.ibm.domino.xsp.adapter.osgi.OSGIModule.doService(OSGIModule.java:126)
>   com.ibm.domino.xsp.adapter.osgi.OSGIService.doService(OSGIService.java:391)
>   com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService(LCDEnvironment.java:341)
>   com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.service(LCDEnvironment.java:297)
>   com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.engine.XspCmdManager.service(XspCmdManager.java:272)"

Answer (score 0):

The Appointment form (actually _CalendarEntry) was designed to be rendered in the Notes client.  I'm guessing it executes @Functions that will only run in the context of Notes.

There is a separate form called _wCalendarEntry.  It has the same alias (Appointment) as does _CalendarEntry, but _wCalendarEntry was designed to be rendered by the web engine.  Ideally you should be able to compute with that form instead.  You can experiment with that idea, but I'm not sure that will work.

As I mentioned in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21785639/domino-rest-post-not-working-for-appointment-note-item-not-found/21799385#21799385), the Domino calendar service is much more suited to creating events on a calendar, but you would have to upgrade to 9.0.1 or at least 9.0.

Comment: I agree the version 9x will be easier that will be my next Domino project, but before that I have to finish the 8.5.x integration. I have now moved the solution to a web services server side and can book a meeting, send a Notice to the RnRmgr and get an answer. The answer I get back doesn't appear to effect the Appointment, do you know if this has to be done manually ? As it may also be an issue with my notice not being connected properly to the Appointment. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: When the system sends an Accept notice for the room, that should automatically be reflected in the View Invitee Status dialog.  You shouldn't have to do any manual steps to make that happen.  If View Invitee Status isn't picking up the Accept notice, there could be a problem with your original invitation.

Comment: I checked and the Invitee Status is set correctly on Accept and Decline, so it looks good for that. For the computewithform I tried the other form I don't get any error but I think it is not detecting the form and so uses the default, in Notes it says unknown form.         Given the workflow is correct, I think I don't require the computewithform functionality.